# Invoking method in another class and storing the returned list

Tags: java, arrays, list, class

As title says i'm trying to invoke the method below from a class called Hill to my public class, i also want to store the return list in a local list.

```
 public static List<Hill> readHills() {

    String destination = "****";

    List<Hill> hill = new ArrayList<>();


    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(destination)));
        String fileContents = "";
        int line = 0;

        while ((fileContents = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line == 0) {
                line++;
                continue;
            } else {
                String[] entries = fileContents.split(",");
                Hill placeholder = new Hill(Integer.parseInt(entries[0]), entries[1], entries[2], Double.parseDouble(entries[4]), Double.parseDouble(entries[5]), Double.parseDouble(entries[6]));
                hill.add(placeholder);
                line++;
            }
        }
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("Unable to find file");
    }

    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    return hill;
}
```

This is the method where i'm trying to invoke the method above

```
public static void exercise5b() {
    Hill mylist = new Hill();
    //List<Integer> mylist = Hill.readHills();
}
```

however when doing this I get an error over Hill(); stating Hill can not be applied within Hill(). The code below also shows what my class Hill contains

```
class Hill {

public int number;
public String name;
public String county;
public double height;
public double latitude;
public double longitude;

Hill (int number, String name, String county, double height, double latitude, double longitude){
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
    this.county = county;
    this.height = height;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
```

Comment: you've overridden the default constructor so you must provide the parameters for the "Hill" constructor when constructing the object. Alternatively you can create a constructor without any params and then it would be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a constructor without any parameters :

```
public Hill() {
}
```

Or you should to pass all the parameters to your constructor.

So you can create an Object of class Hill and call your method :

```
Hill mylist = new Hill();
List<Hill> list = mylist.readHills();
```

1. Your method return a Hill Object and not an Integer
2. You can't name your list with same name of your Object
3. because you are setting static in your method you can call it like this `List<Hill> list = Hill.readHills();`, you don't need to create an Object of type Hill

---

**Edit**

Another problem, i think your indexes is not correct here :

```
    Hill placeholder = new Hill(Integer.parseInt(entries[0]), entries[1], 
            entries[2], Double.parseDouble(entries[4]), Double.parseDouble(entries[5]), 
    //--------------^------------------------------^        
            Double.parseDouble(entries[6]));
```

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6` error happen when your array not contain this index.

Comment: Ahh ok makes sense, that changes my question a bit then, is it possible to return the list in readHills() without passing the constructor as i don't have all the parameters as they are in that said list.

Comment: Just saw your edit saying its possible and implemented it but getting  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

Comment: @beeman this is another problem, but i think you make a tiny mistake check my edit i will tell you where